# Get type of a variable and create new instance of this type

Tags: class, typescript

Lets say I have a base class with some property dataItems which is array of DataItem:

```
export class BaseClass{
   dataItems:DataItems[];
}
```

Then I have several classes which extend BaseClass and their dataItems property is an array of some class which extends DataItems:

```
export class BetterClass extends BaseClass{
   dataItems:BetterDataItems[];
}

export class BestClass extends BaseClass{
   dataItems:BestDataItems[];
}
```

Now I want to add a method in BaseClass which creates dataItems and adds them to array. Would it be possible to do all of this in BaseClass? I need to create instance of BetterDataItems or BestDataItems, depending on the class used.

At the moment I simply added:

```
dataItemType: typeof DataItem;
```

property to BaseClass and in each class extending BaseClass I override this variable with the proper data item type:

in BetterClass:

```
dataItemType: typeof BetterDataItem = BetterDataItem;
```

in BestClass:

```
dataItemType: typeof BestDataItem = BestDataItem;
```

And then, in BaseClass I do this:

```
var dataItem = new this.dataItemType();
```

This works fine but my question is - would it be possible to avoid having `dataItemType` property at all? Can I find a type of `dataItems` array and create a new instance then?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript 1.6 code:

```
class DataItems {

}

class BaseClass {
   dataItems:DataItems[];
   dataItemType: typeof DataItems = DataItems;
}
```

compiles to:

```
var DataItems = (function () {
    function DataItems() {
    }
    return DataItems;
})();
var BaseClass = (function () {
    function BaseClass() {
        this.dataItemType = DataItems;
    }
    return BaseClass;
})();
```

And you can see that type information for `dataItems` property is lost in `BaseClass`. That's how TypeScript compiler works. [It does not support runtime checking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1573). So answer to your question is no.

---

Your workaround with `dataItemType: typeof BetterDataItem = BetterDataItem;` works because you make the TypeScript compiler to add JS command:  `this.dataItemType = BetterDataItem;` which can be used later.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1: You could override the method in each sub class...

```
export class BaseClass{
   dataItems:DataItem[];

   create() {
       this.dataItems.push(new DataItem());
   }
}

export class BetterClass extends BaseClass{
   dataItems:BetterDataItem[];

   create() {
       this.dataItems.push(new BetterDataItem());
   }
}

export class BestClass extends BaseClass{
   dataItems:BestDataItem[];

      create() {
       this.dataItems.push(new BestDataItem());
   }
}
```

Option 2: But if you introduce a generic base class, you can remove the need to define the dataItems property on each class and also create different instances.

```
type MyT = typeof DataItem;

export class GenericBaseClass<T extends DataItem> {
    dataItems:T[];

    constructor(private dataType: MyT) {

    }

    create() {
        this.dataItems.push(<T>new this.dataType())
    }

}

export class BaseClass extends GenericBaseClass<DataItem> {
   constructor() {
       super(DataItem);
   }
}

export class BetterClass extends GenericBaseClass<DataItem> {
   constructor() {
       super(BetterDataItem);
   }
}

export class BestClass extends GenericBaseClass<DataItem> {
   constructor() {
       super(BestDataItem);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1; For the sake of completeness, I think you can use `instanceof` operator in `BaseClass` but it is really an anti-pattern in this case. (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf 4.13 Type Assertions)

Comment: Thanks. So I assume it is not possible to simply get a type of a class from a variable and then create a class? instanceof would require checking each type, so it is really not a good solution.